# qml dialog removing ok button

Tags: qt, dialog, qml

I want to create a custom dialog in qml without the ok button.
this is my code :

```
Dialog {
    id: DialogId
    title: appName
}
```

when the dialog is opened there is an Ok button.
I'm using QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Comment: Use `standardButtons: StandardButton.NoButton` to remove the default button. But in this case you could just create `Window` to have full control on layout.

Comment: @folibis thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `standardButtons` controls wich buttons are in your dialog.

The default value is `StandardButton.Ok`

If you don't whant any button you need to re-implement `contentItem`

For instance:

```
contentItem: Rectangle {
    color: "lightskyblue"
    implicitWidth: 400
    implicitHeight: 100
    Text {
        text: "Hello blue sky!"
        color: "navy"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```